# Getting statistics from Coverity

Tags: static-analysis, coverity

I am looking for a way for acquiring the Coverity summary page (The page we see after login to Coverity). Simple web scraping doesn't fit in to this context as a login is required prior to acquire this page.

I am just wondering if there is a API provided for Coverity to periodically acquire those information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, read the *Coverity Connect Web Services API* manual for their SOAP protocol.  Sadly, the old [place](http://go.coverity.com/Communities.html) to ask questions has had a “down for maintenance. We will be back in early 2016!” message for a long time, and their certificate recently expired; so you now need to override your security preferences even to get the failure message.  I reported the problem to Coverity/Synopsys a while ago, but they’re not going to fix it soon.